# Symfony, Keep Get Argumments in Search form after submit

Tags: php, symfony

**Hi,**

i have created a search form using GET method, to my indexAction, the form contains virtual fields.

i created the logic for searching inside the indexAction.

My problem is when i submit the form, all inputs values become empty.

What i want is to keep the values passed as arguments in form inputs

**here is my FormType :**

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Chercher',
            )
        ))
        ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Person',
            'placeholder' => 'Choisir client',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'select2',
            )
        ))
        ->add('date_start', DateTimeType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'inherit_data' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'name' => 'date_start',
                'class' => 'datepicker',
                'placeholder' => 'Date début',
                'value' => ''
            )
        ))
        ->add('date_end', DateTimeType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'inherit_data' => true,
            'attr' => array(
                'name' => 'date_end',
                'class' => 'datepicker',
                'placeholder' => 'Date fin',
                'value' => ''
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

**The indexAction :**

```
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $getArgs = $request->query->get('order');
    dump($getArgs);
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\Search\OrderType', new Order(), array('get' => $getArgs));
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Order');
    $query = $getArgs ? $repo->findAllMatched($q) : $repo->createQueryBuilder('o');

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $orders = $paginator->paginate($query);

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Order:index.html.twig', array(
        'orders' => $orders,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Any suggestions are wellcome.

Comment: Store the values in the session then retrieve them this next time you need to display the form.

Comment: i'm using the generated form inputs from the formType Object, i dont have inputs on my template file because i render {{ form }} , so it's not a proper idea to change all the code to html inputs & use session data there !!

Comment: No idea what you just said.  You want to preserve title, client and dates?  Store them in the session and feed them to you form when you create it in your controller.

Comment: @BoubouhKarim Can you show your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, i resolved the problem in this way :

```
            <div class="nav box-search">
            <form method="GET" class="form-inline">
                <div class="pull-right">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{ 'actions.search' | trans }}</button>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-left">
                    {% set params = app.request.query.all %}
                    {{- form_widget(form.title, { 'attr': {'value': params.order.title| default('')} }) -}}
                    {{ form_widget(form.client,  {value: params.order.client| default('') }) }}
                    {{- form_widget(form.date_start, { 'attr': {'value': params.order.date_start| default('')} }) -}}
                        <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i>
                    {{- form_row(form.date_end, { 'attr': {'value': params.order.date_end| default('')} }) -}}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

It's not that bad solution, but what i would is to have this parameters configuration in the FormType.